# Trouble storing a contents of a drive sector into character array using BIOS interrupt 0x13

Tags: c, x86, bios

We are working on a kernel in our Operating Systems class in C using bcc and some simulator software a professor wrote. The current step I am stuck on is to read a sector from a floppy using a 0x13 BIOS interrupt, storing it in a character array, and then printing it to the screen. Once we finish our kernel.c we build it into a floppy.img file. Then we load a .txt file into sector 30 of the floppy we are reading so we can test that our readSector function works properly. Finally we run the floppy.img file in a simulator that will simulate an OS

```
int main(){
    void printString(char*);
    void readString(char*);
    void readSector(char*, int);
    int mod(int, int);//Modulus Function
    int div(int, int);//Divison Function

    char buffer[512];  
    readSector(buffer,30);
        printString(buffer);
    while(1);
}
```

The printString function works fine and I have been using it for debugging purposes

```
void printString(char* chars){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; chars[i] != '\0'; i++){
    interrupt(0x10, 0xe*256+chars[i], 0, 0, 0);
    }
}//printString
```

We weren't really given a clear constructor for the 0x13 interrupt, I think this is the right order but I'm not 100%. When I run the simulator it prints the "Called interrupt 0x13" but doesn't print anything out after that, when it should print the contents of buffer from main.

```
void readSector(char* buffer, int sector){
    int relativeSector = mod(sector,18)+1;  //sector%18
    int head = mod(div(sector,18),2);   //(sector/18)%2
    int track = div(sector,36);     //sector/36
    interrupt(0x13, 2, 1, buffer, track, relativeSector, head, 0);  //0x13, AH, AL, BX, CH, CL, DH, DL
    printString("Called interrupt 0x13\0");

}
```

Since bcc doesn't includ mod/div I made these based on some given pseudocode

```
int mod(int a, int b){//a == modulend,  b == modulosor
    while(a > b){
        a =a-b;
    }
    return a;
}//mod

int div(int a, int b){//a == dividend, b == divisor, q == quotient
    int q = 0;
    while((q*b) <= a){
        q++;
    }
    return q-1;
}//div
```

I'm not 100% sure how the 0x13 interrupt works, I assumed that it would read sector 30 and write it into the buffer array. My professor took a look at this for a few minutes and said it looks okay but wasn't sure why it wasn't working. Going to see him tomorrow to investigate this further, but there's a few more steps due by Wednesday and I'm getting antsy trying to figure this one out. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: [Ralph Brown's Interrupt List (RBIL)](http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm) is the best source of BIOS (and DOS) interrupt information. Int 13h/ah=2 (read sector) is documented [here](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0607.htm)

Comment: Does the simulator your prof apparently wrote have a name? Has me curious.

Comment: This is the simulator https://github.com/mdblack/simulator, for the project we were just given simulator.jar @MichaelPetch

Comment: I'm not sure about your other code, and I haven't looked over your math. But if all the functions are correct, one other issue would be making sure that ES=DS (can't tell from this code).